# Social media links like Facebook, twitter, Google+ is not opening in NativeScript Webview for iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, webview, nativescript

All app functionality working fine in iOS but when I click on promotional social media links in the iOS device then it has been unresponsive, same thing working fine in android.

Is there any plugin required to open the links or any permission required for iOS devices.

Thanks

Comment: You mean, opening Facebook, Twitter etc., apps from your app with the link?

Comment: I want to open my official page in different social media sites so people can able to follow. But when I click on facebook, google+ etc it's not opening in safari browser

Comment: Would you mind sharing a sample HTML link you are using?

Comment: Basically, I passed URL in the web-view. Is there any code required for iOS to handle hyperlink??

Comment: Until you want to open the hyperlink within Webview, you don't have to handle anything specifically.

Comment: Basic flow:
On login page I have few social media Icons like twitter fb etc....when we click on social media icon it should redirect to that social media page.
This thing working fine in Android.But in iOS when I click on icons it doesn't works.
I want to open these links on safari browser or any browser that installed in that devices.

Comment: Without seeing your web page where you have those icons / links, I may not be able to give you any direction here.